# sorting weird in posgres with locale en_us

Tags: postgresql, sorting, locale

I'm using postgres, and I have a data base with encoding=UTF8 and lc_collate=en_US.UTF-8. When I try to select some items order by a column(type is varchar), the returned result is weird.

For example:

```
SELECT name FROM unnest(ARRAY[
      'abc',  '#abc', 'abc a' , '!abc' , ' abc', '~abc'
]) name ORDER BY name.
```

The return sorting result from postgres is:

```
[ "abc", "~abc", " abc", "!abc","#abc", "abc a"]
```

seems it's not sorted with the byte code, it's weird that those strings with special characters are listed between "abc" and "abc a". 
I'm wondering is it the correct sorting in en_US locale?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses the collation support from the operating system, I can reproduce your sort order with Postgres 10 installed on CentOS 7, but not on Windows 10. So it seems that (at least CentOS) thinks this sort order makes sense.

However, you can force a specific collation by using the `collate` keyword.

```
SELECT name 
FROM unnest(ARRAY['abc',  '#abc', 'abc a' , '!abc' , ' abc', '~abc']) name 
ORDER BY name collate "C"
```

returns:

```
name 
-----
 abc 
!abc 
#abc 
abc  
abc a
~abc
```

Details on Postgres' collation support can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, when I try to use postgres installed in windows(lc_collate=English_United States.1252) , the sorting results will be: 
'name 
    -----
     abc 
    !abc 
    #abc
   ~abc 
    abc  
    abc a '
which would make more sense on myside.

Comment: However my platform doesn't support lc_collate=English_United States.1252, and is local C represents a common sorting rules? because it seems still weird that the ~abc lists in the last while other strings with special charecter list in the start position. Do you know how this international sorting commonly implemented if I have also chinese charcters to sort? I think UTF-8 behaves differently in different OS system?

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me (a messed up sorting issue): ORDER BY c.name COLLATE "sv_SE" ASC